# File upload for e-mail attachment using Angularjs

Tags: php, angularjs, file-upload, phpmailer, slim

I have a form which i programmed with Angularjs and PHP (Slim Framework).
In the form the user needs to have the possibility to upload a file (pdf), which will be sent as an attachment of an automatic-generated e-mail (which is sent with phpmailer) after the form is submitted.

I have taken research for the solution of my problem but I didn't find anything that worked for me.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload/

Comment: I've tried this, but it didn't work. Can you show me an example?

Answer (score 0):

First you will need to setup your HTML.  You can also find an example [here](http://nervgh.github.io/pages/angular-file-upload/examples/simple/).

```
<div popover="Open a previously saved project." popover-trigger="mouseenter" class="form-button" ng-file-select ng-model="file">Open Existing Project</div>
```

**NOTE** I have a popover here, there is an error when you upload, the popover does not go away, I would suggest either not using it or posting a solution here please ;)

Then use a watch on a variable that is set for your file upload.

```
//Watch file for changes to run open file dialog
$scope.$watch('file', function () {
    //Only make the ajax call if there is a file to upload
    if ($scope.file) {
        ajaxFactory.openFileDialog($scope.file, setProjectData);
    }
});
```

In my case I have an ajax wrapper that calls an MVC Controller

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Save a file to the server
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        var retObject = new JsonReturnObject();

        try
        {
            // Read bytes from http input stream
            BinaryReader b = new BinaryReader(file.InputStream);
            var binData = b.ReadBytes((int)file.InputStream.Length);

            retObject.StringPayload = NttCommon.GetString(binData);
            retObject.Success = true;

            b.Close();
            b.Dispose();
        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException ane)
        {
            Log.Error("An ArgumentNullException occured while uploading to FileManagerController.", ane);
            retObject.StringPayload = ane.InnerException.ToString();
        }
        catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException aoore)
        {
            Log.Error("An ArgumentOutOfRangeException occured while uploading to FileManagerController.", aoore);
            retObject.StringPayload = aoore.InnerException.ToString();
        }
        catch (DecoderFallbackException dfe)
        {
            Log.Error("An DecoderFallbackException occured while uploading to FileManagerController.", dfe);
            retObject.StringPayload = dfe.InnerException.ToString();
        }
        catch (ArgumentException ae)
        {
            Log.Error("An ArgumentException occured while uploading to FileManagerController.", ae);
            retObject.StringPayload = ae.InnerException.ToString();
        }
        catch (IOException ioe)
        {
            Log.Error("An IOException occured while uploading to FileManagerController.", ioe);
            retObject.StringPayload = ioe.InnerException.ToString();
        }
        catch (ObjectDisposedException ode)
        {
            Log.Error("An ObjectDisposedException occured while uploading to FileManagerController.", ode);
            retObject.StringPayload = ode.InnerException.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.Error("An unknown exception occured while uploading to FileManagerController.", e);
            retObject.StringPayload = e.InnerException.ToString();
        }

        return FormatJsonReturnResult.ReturnStandardJsonResult(retObject);
    }
```

Comment: where do i need to put the ajax wrapper? In my controller?

Comment: The ajax wrapper is just a JavaScript file that contains ajax calls to your server.  It will vary for you because you are using PHP.  My example is ASP.Net.  I am using ajax to call an MVC controller, you might be calling a web service or something else.  I use the ajax wrapper to keep all ajax calls in one place so I know where to find them.  If your site is small, it does not hurt to place your ajax calls in with the rest of your JS code, but it can easily get cluttered.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with uploadify